# python lxml.html.parse not reading url

Tags: python, lxml, python-requests

Why is `html.parse(url)` failing, when using `requests` then `html.fromstring` works and `html.parse(url2)` works?  lxml 3.4.2

```
    Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> from lxml import html
>>> url = 'http://www.oddschecker.com'
>>> page = requests.get(url).content
>>> tree = html.fromstring(page)
>>> html.parse(url)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    html.parse(url)
  File "C:\program files\Python27\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 788, in parse
    return etree.parse(filename_or_url, parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3301, in lxml.etree.parse (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:72453)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1791, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:105915)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1817, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:106214)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1721, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:105213)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1122, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:100163)
  File "parser.pxi", line 580, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:94286)
  File "parser.pxi", line 690, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:95722)
  File "parser.pxi", line 618, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:94754)
IOError: Error reading file 'http://www.oddschecker.com': failed to load HTTP resource
>>> url2 = 'http://www.google.com'
>>> html.parse(url2)
<lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x00000000033BAF88>
```

Comment: Maybe `oddschecker.com` is rejecting the User Agent from `lxml`

Comment: @mattm Could be. Any idea what user agent lxml claims to be?

Comment: @mattm alecxe's answer confirms your suggestion that it's rejecting lxml's user agent (none).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding some clarification to @michael_stackof's answer. This particular URL would return `403 Forbidden` status code if `User-Agent` header is not supplied.

According to the [`lxml`'s source code](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/fbff6a6b4bf684da083123a1e414605005065831/src/lxml/ElementInclude.py#L109), it uses `urllib2.urlopen()` without supplying a `User-Agent` header which results into `403`, which results into `failed to load HTTP resource` error.

On the other hand, `requests` provides a default `User-Agent` header if not explicitly passed:

```
>>> requests.get(url).request.headers['User-Agent']
'python-requests/2.3.0 CPython/2.7.6 Darwin/14.1.0'
```

To prove the point, set the `User-Agent` header to `None` and see:

```
>>> requests.get(url).status_code
200
>>> requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': None}).status_code
403
```

Comment: That does clarify things.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When the http status not 200, html.parse will quit.

the return status of http://www.oddschecker.com.
[image]

Comment: I tried http://nytimes.com with `html.parse()` and it worked fine. nytimes.com generates some non-200 responses.

Comment: this one . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303567/why-is-the-slash-at-the-end-of-lxml-html-parse-important

Comment: google.com works without a trailing /, as does nytimescom.  oddschecker.com fails with or without a trailing /.  Therefore, I don't understand the link to that question.

Comment: @michael_stackof check out my answer - should clarify things here.